# What is the purpose of C++20 std::common_reference?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, type-traits, c++20

C++20 introduces [`std::common_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference). What is its purpose? Can someone give an example of using it?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`common_reference` came out of my efforts to come up with a conceptualization of STL's iterators that accommodates proxy iterators.

In the STL, iterators have two associated types of particular interest: `reference` and `value_type`. The former is the return type of the iterator's `operator*`, and the `value_type` is the (non-const, non-reference) type of the elements of the sequence.

Generic algorithms often have a need to do things like this:

```cpp
value_type tmp = *it;
```

... so we know that there must be *some* relationship between these two types. For non-proxy iterators the relationship is simple: `reference` is always `value_type`, optionally const and reference qualified. [Early attempts at defining the `InputIterator` concept](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf) required that the expression `*it` was convertible to `const value_type &`, and for most interesting iterators that is sufficient.

I wanted iterators in C++20 to be more powerful than this. For example, consider the needs of a `zip_iterator` that iterates two sequences in lock-step. When you dereference a `zip_iterator`, you get a temporary `pair` of the two iterators' *`reference`* types. So, `zip`'ing a `vector<int>` and a `vector<double>` would have these associated types:

`zip` iterator's `reference` : `pair<int &, double &>`
`zip` iterator's `value_type`: `pair<int, double>`

As you can see, these two types are not related to each other simply by adding top-level cv- and ref qualification. And yet letting the two types be arbitrarily different feels wrong. Clearly there is *some* relationship here. But what is the relationship, and what can generic algorithms that operate on iterators safely assume about the two types?

The answer in C++20 is that for *any* valid iterator type, proxy or not, the types `reference &&` and `value_type &` share a *common reference*. In other words, for some iterator `it` there is some type `CR` which makes the following well-formed:

```cpp
void foo(CR) // CR is the common reference for iterator I
{}

void algo( I it, iter_value_t<I> val )
{
  foo(val); // OK, lvalue to value_type convertible to CR
  foo(*it); // OK, reference convertible to CR
}
```

`CR` is the common reference. All algorithms can rely on the fact that this type exists, and can use `std::common_reference` to compute it.

So, that is the role that `common_reference` plays in the STL in C++20. Generally, unless you are writing generic algorithms or proxy iterators, you can safely ignore it. It's there under the covers ensuring that your iterators are meeting their contractual obligations.

---

EDIT: The OP also asked for an example. This is a little contrived, but imagine it's C++20 and you are given a random-access range `r` of type `R` about which you know nothing, and you want to `sort` the range.

Further imagine that for some reason, you want to use a monomorphic comparison function, like `std::less<T>`. (Maybe you've type-erased the range, and you need to also type-erase the comparison function and pass it through a `virtual`? Again, a stretch.) What should `T` be in `std::less<T>`? For that you would use `common_reference`, or the helper `iter_common_reference_t` which is implemented in terms of it.

```cpp
using CR = std::iter_common_reference_t<std::ranges::iterator_t<R>>;
std::ranges::sort(r, std::less<CR>{});
```

That is guaranteed to work, even if range `r` has proxy iterators.

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but can you clarify what the common reference is in the zip-pair example?

Comment: Ideally, `pair<T&,U&>` and `pair<T,U>&` would have a common reference, and it would be simply `pair<T&,U&>`. However, for `std::pair`, there is no conversion from `pair<T,U>&` to `pair<T&,U&>` even though such a conversion is sound in principle. (This, incidentally, is why we don't have a `zip` view in C++20.)

Comment: @EricNiebler: "*This, incidentally, is why we don't have a zip view in C++20.*" Is there some reason why a zip iterator would have to use `pair`, instead of a type that could be specifically designed for its purpose, with appropriate implicit conversions as needed?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas There is no need to use `std::pair`; any suitable pair-like type with the appropriate conversions will do, and range-v3 defines such a pair-like type. On the Committee, LEWG didn't like the idea of adding to the Standard Library a type that was almost but not quite `std::pair`, be it normative or not, without first doing due diligence about the pros and cons of simply making `std::pair` work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `std::tuple` anyway? I'm not aware of *any* place where a pair is better than a tuple of size 2, though they are both prevalent in the standard and other code.

Comment: `tuple`, `pair`, `tomato`, `to`-`MAH`-`to`. `pair` has this nice feature that you can access the elements with `.first` and `.second`. Structured bindings help with some of the awkwardness of working with `tuple`s,  but not all.

Comment: @EricNiebler So should I overload the unary operator& of the value type for the common_reference to work if I'm writing a proxy iterator? Is there an example?

Comment: Don't overload unary `operator&` for any reason whatsoever. A simple My First Proxy Iterator example doesn't have to be complex, but all the examples I find online are.