# Deviation of std::assignable_from concept

Tags: c++, c++20

Why did they choose to make the `std::assignable_from` concept behave so differently
from its name-sharing type-trait `std::is_assignable`? (Opposed to some of the other name-sharing type-traits and concepts.)

```
static_assert(not std::is_convertible_v<char, std::string>); // ok
static_assert(not std::convertible_to<char, std::string>);   // ok

static_assert(not std::is_constructible_v<std::string, char>); // ok
static_assert(not std::constructible_from<std::string, char>); // ok

static_assert(std::is_assignable_v<std::string&, char>); // ok
static_assert(std::assignable_from<std::string&, char>); // fail
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/6dnKd84fz)

Why didn't they either change `std::is_assignable` to be more in line with `std::assignable_from`, or simply give a different name to `std::assignable_from`?

Please note that I'm not asking what explains the difference in behavior between the type-trait and related concept.

Comment: "*I'm not asking what explains the difference in behavior between the type-trait and related concept.*" Wouldn't that be a useful data point in trying to determine why they're not identical?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, and by all means, feel free to use that to provide a good answer. I just wanted to emphasize that I'm not looking for an answer that boils down to highlighting the differences from the possible implementations that are available on [cppreference.com](https://www.cppreference.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The rationale behind std::assignable\_from possible implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60138440/the-rationale-behind-stdassignable-from-possible-implementation)

Comment: Furthermore, even if might not initially seem so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66938093/14462794) basically explains the crux behind all of this. The deviation of `std::assignable_from` has everything to do with `std::common_reference` and the semantic equality requirements of `std::assignable_from`.

Comment: @Rane I already read up on that question before asking this one. It doesn't answer the question I'm asking here.

Comment: @303 The `std::common_reference_with` requirement inherently explains why `std::assignable_from` gives different results compared to `std::is_assignable_v`. Moreover, `std::common_reference` is in the very root of the design of how [the original Concepts proposal defines equality](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3351.pdf#subsection.3.3). Now, if you really want to ask why they designed it this way, I advice you to send an email to Stroustrup or Sutton (authors of the paper).