# Does `equality_­comparable_with` need to require `common_reference`?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The [concept `equality_­comparable_with<T, U>`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/concepts#concept.equalitycomparable-4) is intended to declare that objects of type `T` and `U` can be compared equal to each other, and if they are, then this has the expected meaning. That's fine.

However, this concept also requires `common_reference_t<T&, U&>` to exist. The primary impetus for `common_reference` and its attendant functionality seems to be to [enable proxy iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59024241/734069), to have a place to represent the relationship between `reference` and `value_type` for such iterators.

That's great, but... what does that have to do with testing if a `T` and a `U` can be compared equal to one another? Why does the standard require that `T` and `U` have a common reference relationship just to allow you to compare them equal?

This creates oddball situations where it's very difficult to have two types which don't reasonably have a common-reference relationship that are logically comparable. For example, `vector<int>` and `pmr::vector<int>` logically ought to be comparable. But they can't be because there's no reasonable common-reference between the two otherwise unrelated types.

Comment: @Marshall would approve of this question.

Comment: Well even `assignable_from` requires `common_reference` ...

Comment: @cpplearner: That at least somewhat makes sense, as assignment is a property that proxy references and values are expected to share.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This goes all the way back to the [Palo Alto report](https://wg21.link/n3351), §3.3 and D.2.

For the cross-type concepts to be mathematically sound, you need to define what the cross-type comparison means. For `equality_comparable_with`, `t == u` generally means that `t` and `u` are equal, but what does it even mean for two values of different types to be equal? The design says that cross-type equality is defined by mapping them to the common (reference) type (this conversion is required to preserve the value).

Where the strong axioms of `equality_comparable_with` is not desirable, the standard uses the exposition-only concept *`weakly-equality-comparable-with`*, and that concept doesn't require a common reference. It is, however, a "semantic abomination" (in the words of Casey Carter) and is exposition-only for that reason: it allows having `t == u` and `t2 == u` but `t != t2` (this is actually necessary for sentinels).

Comment: That's interesting, but that doesn't explain why the "mathematically sound" solution involves this "common reference" type instead of... well, *anything else*. That is, why does it involve doing this implicit reference conversion business instead of something that would allow for logically mathematically sound concepts that cannot permit conversions (like `container<T, stuff>` and `container<U, other_stuff>` being comparable if `T` is comparable to `U`)? Is it just that `common_reference` was available, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: It lacks the idea that the conversion function to the common_reference type is an epimorphism.

Comment: Does `equality_comparable_with` without the common-reference requirements actually allow `t == u` and `t2 == u` but `t != t2`, or does it just mean that `t == t2` doesn't compile?

Comment: @Justin The part that disallows `t != t2` [is the part that uses the common reference](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/concept.equalitycomparable#4.sentence-1).

Comment: @T.C. I see; I misread "`t == u` and `t2 == u` but `t != t2`" as the transitive property, but now I understand what you mean. I can see that iterator+sentinel equality is not really equality, but it is instead testing membership of an equivalence class ( `{x : x is not at the end}` and `{x : x is at the end}` ). I suppose it would be like working with integers, then saying `0 == 2 mod 2`, which is true when we re-type as Z_2, but it's not actually an `==` for Z.