# How can I tell the compiler that MyCustomType is equality_comparable_with SomeOtherType?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Suppose I have a `MyCustomType` that has comparisons with `SomeOtherType`:

```
struct SomeOtherType {
    int value;

    constexpr bool operator==(const SomeOtherType& rhs) const = default;
};

struct MyCustomType {
    int x;

    constexpr bool operator==(const MyCustomType& rhs) const = default;
    constexpr bool operator==(const SomeOtherType& rhs) const {
        return x == rhs.value;
    }
    friend constexpr bool operator==(const SomeOtherType& lhs, const MyCustomType& rhs) {
        return lhs.value == rhs.x;
    }
};
```

This is great, but `static_assert(std::equality_comparable_with<MyCustomType, SomeOtherType>);` fails, meaning that I can't use them for heterogenous lookup in the `std::ranges` algorithms:

> ```
> error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::common_reference<const MyCustomType&, const SomeOtherType&>'
> ```

I understand why this fails: we may have an `operator==`, but we don't meet the common-reference requirements (see also [Does `equality_­comparable_with` need to require `common_reference`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61177302/1896169) ). However, my type is, practically speaking, equality comparable with `SomeOtherType`. How can I convince the compiler that this is the case?

Comment: Why not implement `const bool operator==(const SomeOtherType& sot) const;`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Because I accidentally mixed terminology when I wrote this. `SomeOtherType` is `int` in this case. I'll come through and clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Philosophically, the common-reference requirements of `std::equality_comparable_with` are explicitly encoding the implicit statement made when writing a heterogenous `operator==(T, U)` to actually mean equality*: there is some common supertype "`T` union `U`" for which the `operator==` is equality. This "`T` union `U`" doesn't actually exist in the code for `MyCustomType` and `SomeOtherType`. If we make the type actually exist by specializing `std::common_reference_t`, then we can meet `std::equality_comparable_with`.

*Some types use `operator==` for equivalence rather than equality (e.g. iterators+sentinels), and as such should not and do not meet `std::equality_comparable_with`.

---

We can use the [`std::basic_common_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference) customization point to specify a proxy reference:

> The class template `basic_common_reference` is a customization point that allows users to influence the result of `common_reference` for user-defined types (typically proxy references).

For this to work, we need:

- `eq_proxy_ref<T>` which acts like a reference for `T`.
- `MyCustomType` must be implicitly convertible to `eq_proxy_ref<T>`.
- `SomeOtherType` must be implicitly convertible to `eq_proxy_ref<T>`.
- `basic_common_reference` of `MyCustomType` and `SomeOtherType` must return this `eq_proxy_ref<int>`. A `eq_proxy_ref<MyCustomProxy>` could work too if you wanted to avoid leaking the internals of `MyCustomType`.
- `eq_proxy_ref<T>` must have comparison operators between itself.
- `eq_proxy_ref<T>` must obey the spirit of the requirement.

Beware, however, that `std::common_reference_t` is used for more than just equality, including `std::three_way_comparable_with`, `std::totally_ordered_with`, and some of the Ranges algorithms or views. As such, your `eq_proxy_ref<T>` should actually be a common reference for your two types, not just a mechanism to enable equality.

An example meeting these constraints follows:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

// Assuming you don't own SomeOtherType:
template <typename T>
class MyCustomTypeEqProxy {
    template <typename>
    friend class MyCustomTypeEqProxy;

private:
    T ref_;

public:
    template <typename U>
        requires std::convertible_to<U, T>
    constexpr MyCustomTypeEqProxy(U ref)
        : ref_(ref)
    {}

    constexpr MyCustomTypeEqProxy(const SomeOtherType& rhs)
            requires std::convertible_to<const int&, T>
        : ref_(rhs.value)
    {}

    template <typename U>
        requires std::equality_comparable_with<T, U>
    constexpr bool operator==(const MyCustomTypeEqProxy<U>& rhs) const {
        return ref_ == rhs.ref_;
    };
};

struct MyCustomType {
    int x;

    constexpr bool operator==(const MyCustomType& rhs) const = default;
    constexpr bool operator==(const SomeOtherType& rhs) const {
        return x == rhs.value;
    }
    friend constexpr bool operator==(const SomeOtherType& lhs, const MyCustomType& rhs) {
        return lhs.value == rhs.x;
    }

    constexpr operator MyCustomTypeEqProxy<int>() const { return MyCustomTypeEqProxy<int>(x); }
};

namespace std {
// May not be needed, but allows the custom proxy reference to expand to common references
// of what we're comparing against.
template <typename T, typename U, template <typename> class TQ, template <typename> class UQ>
struct basic_common_reference<::MyCustomTypeEqProxy<T>, U, TQ, UQ> {
    using type = ::MyCustomTypeEqProxy< std::common_reference_t<T, UQ<U>> >;
};
template <typename T, typename U, template <typename> class TQ, template <typename> class UQ>
struct basic_common_reference<T, ::MyCustomTypeEqProxy<U>, TQ, UQ> {
    using type = ::MyCustomTypeEqProxy< std::common_reference_t<TQ<T>, U> >;
};

// Tell std::common_reference_t about MyCustomTypeEqProxy
template <template <typename> class LQ, template <typename> class RQ>
struct basic_common_reference<::MyCustomType, ::SomeOtherType, LQ, RQ> {
    using type = ::MyCustomTypeEqProxy<int>;
};
template <template <typename> class LQ, template <typename> class RQ>
struct basic_common_reference<::SomeOtherType, ::MyCustomType, LQ, RQ> {
    using type = ::MyCustomTypeEqProxy<int>;
};
}
```

[Compiler Explorer link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e75fGf74d)

I suspect that I missed some nuances, but this is enough to meet `std::equality_comparable_with`.

Comment: This feels so icky to me. `std::common_reference_t` isn't just for equality AFAIK, so doing this seems questionable