# Why doesn't std::ranges::find compile while std::find works fine?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    struct S {
        int  a;
        int  b;
        bool operator==(int other) const { return a == other; }
    };
    std::vector<S> iv{
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4}
    };

    // this works
    if (auto const it{std::find(iv.begin(), iv.end(), 1)}; it != iv.end()) {
        std::cout << "Found!\n" << "\n";
    }

    //std::ranges::find(iv, 2); // <-- why does this not compile
    
}
```

My impression was that the call convention of ranges would be a 1-to-1 mapping of the corresponding original algorithm (i.e., just skip the `.begin()` and `.end()`, and it should work as before).

Clearly this is not the case here. What am I missing?

A link to the code:
https://godbolt.org/z/3a6z9c5of

Comment: hmmm I don't see "find()" in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges

Comment: @BЈовић See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/find

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ranges::find` uses [`ranges::equal_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ranges/equal_to) by default to compare the elements of the range with the value, and the call operator of `ranges::equal_to` constrains the two types to satisfy [`equality_comparable_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/equality_comparable), which is `S` and `int` in your example.

`equal_comparable_with` requires `S` to be comparable with itself and needs to have a common reference with `const int&`, which is not your case.

The simple workaround is to use the projection function to project `S` to `S::a`

```
if (auto const it{std::ranges::find(iv, 1, &S::a)}; it != iv.end()) {
    std::cout << "Found!\n" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What is the motivation for `equality_comparable_with` to require the existence of a common reference? What does it have to do with comparison?

Comment: @Evg See [Does `equality_­comparable_with` need to require `common_reference`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177302/does-equality-comparable-with-need-to-require-common-reference)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the answer there doesn't really explain the motivation, "the design says", that's all. I guess I need to study the document that answer refers to.

Comment: @Evg Well, what does it even mean to say that an `S` (a type with two `int`s in it) is "equal" to an `int`? There are certain properties that we think about when we think about equality... so `S{1, 2} == 1` and `S{1, 3} == 1`, does that imply that `S{1, 2} == S{1, 3}`? But `S` isn't even comparable to itself, so what can we even meaningfully say about this? This example strikes me more like it's using `==` for the syntactic convenience of `find` more than anything else.

Comment: @Evg: motivation of constraints are to have meaningful contraints, i.e just have `operator<` (for ordering) is "strange" (so no `operator >`) (even if it is indeed the "old" C++ way).