# Projections to class members

Tags: c++, c++20, projection

So I [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77237117/stdrangesfind-vs-stdfind) had a question about using the ranges variant of the `std::ranges::find` algorithm and the answer used a projection:

```cpp
if (auto const it{std::ranges::find(iv, 1, &S::a)}; it != iv.end()) {
    std::cout << "Found!\n" << "\n";
}
```

Specifically the `&S::a` part.
Normally I have seen a lambda being used in this place, but here we use a pointer to a class member. Is this transformed into a lambda or is there some overload selection going on?

Can someone break down how this, seemingly magic, works?

P.S.
If someone have a suggestion for a better title, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&S::a` is [a pointer to the data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/pointer-to-class-data-member) of class `S`. Just like pointers to member functions, they both can be invoked through specific class objects, so they are *callable*s.

In c++20, constraint functions (which are under namespace `ranges`) in `<algorithm>` and range adaptors in `<ranges>` (or most of the standard library) uniformly invoke callables through [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).

`std::invoke` is a generalized interface for calling callables. In addition to calling ordinary functions with the common form of `f(x)`, it can also handle pointers to data members/functions.

Let's go back to your example. Basically, `ranges::find` determines whether the current element is equal to the value via the condition `if (std::invoke(proj, *it) == value)`, where `proj` is `&S::a` and `*it` returns an object of type `S`.

So `std::invoke(&S::a, obj_s)` returns a reference to the member `a` of the `obj_s`, which is a reference to an `int`.

Comment: The Wizard is back! Thanks again. 
This was exactly the level of detail I was hoping for. The missing piece for me was that the pointer to a _data_ member is callable. Interesting property!

Comment: I wouldn't say that a pointer to data member is callable. It really isn't. You can however pass it to a function, and `std::invoke` has an overload that "does the right thing" with it.

Comment: @super, Well, they are invokable through an instance of the class, which returns a reference to that instances' member. So quasi-callable, maybe?

Comment: @super -- a pointer-to-data-member is a **callable object** as defined in the C++ standard. `std::invoke` operates on callable objects.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/function.objects#func.def-4