Is there a way to get projection to zipped vectors std::tuple without lambda?
As shown in the code below I can sort zipped vectors with std::ranges::sort, using lambda to specify that sorting should be done by the first vector. Is there a way to use projection, specifying the tuple field name (or something else) like shown in the examples (2) and (3)?
The example (2) worked in ranges3 where the element was implemented as std::pair (or at least it was possible to access it this way). Now with standard library ranges, it is implemented with tuples and this approach doesn’t work.
Can I get this done without lambda here?
Why do I care? I need to keep separate and available comparator and projection to use with my tuned versions. Additional benefit is less code, easier to write, read and support.
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> x_values = { 3.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f };
    std::vector<float> y_values = { 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f };

    // (1) Compiles
    std::ranges::sort(std::ranges::views::zip(x_values, y_values), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return std::get<0>(lhs) < std::get<0>(rhs);
    });

    // (2) Doesn't compile since in ranges they use tuples
    std::ranges::sort(std::ranges::views::zip(x_values, y_values), std::less<>{}, &std::pair<int, int>::first);

    // (3) I guess doesn't compile since get is a member function template, not a member field
    std::ranges::sort(std::ranges::views::zip(x_values, y_values), std::less<>{}, &std::get<0>);
}

Here is the demo.
(Too verbose logs have been removed from the question, since we already have the answers and the logs are not needed. Let me know if you want me to get them back).

In your demo, (1) already doesn't compile. All I did was comment out (2) and (3)

No. But it's not hard to implement as a variable template: template<auto N> auto myget=[](auto&& t){return get<N>(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t));};

lambda is short: [](const auto& t) { return std::get<0>(t); } Demo. You can still write helper class to factorize that lambda.

@IgorTandetnik, thank you for catching this. Actually this becomes even more interesting. It compiles fine with MSVC and as you have shown, doesn't compile with CLang. Any idea what could be the reason for this discrepancy or it would be better to open another question for this?

@Red.Wave, thank you. Works like a charm with only one question on the table (the same as in my previous comment to Igor T. It works fine with MSVC and doesn't work with CLang. What could cause the difference?

@Jarod42, thank you. Helped a lot. I forgot that I can use lambda to make a call on the element during the projection.  The same solution as from Red.Wave, but in yours it is easier to see the idea.

@Red.Wave, just about "no" in your comment. cigien in the answer below has shown that this is really possible. Have you just missed this way or I misunderstand it or your "no"? Just curious if I got his answer correctly, but it seems to be the perfect match (although quite verbose syntax).

@DamirTenishev Please see the update to my answer. In this particular situation, the solution is UB so you shouldn't use it (even though it will appear to work). Also, please remove the update to your question about Clang not compiling the first line. That's a separate question (and to which the answer is to use llvm's stdlib, with -stdlib=libc++ https://godbolt.org/z/WP5h7on4r)

@IgorTandetnik, the issue with CLang has been solved thanks to cigien's explanation (I just forgot to add  -stdlib=libc++ compiler option). Thank you again for catching this.

@Red.Wave, thank you again, just to make sure I didn't miss something, your solution introduces the template, but makes the client code shorter. Is this the only difference with the solution from Jarod42 or I miss something more important (safety, something else)? Just want to consider all sides before putting in code.

@cigien, thank you so much for both answers. It helps. The question has been updated as requested.

Honestly, this is such a recurring problem that it never hurts to keep a utility like this in your code base.

@DamirTenishev AFAIK std library doesn't provide any shorthand for the usage in question. Future implementations of std may silently change the declaration of static function templates as CPO, which may create none-std possiblity for the use case in question. But I always find wrapping std::get in a CPO useful; if you need it once, you'll probably use it again. So in a personal library, you can gradually make such simple adjustments. I fail to see why everyone waits for ISO to handle such simple matters.


I need to keep separate and available comparator and projection to use with my tuned versions. Additional benefit is less code, easier to write, read and support.

What I can think of is, old-school functors, which is customized something like:
template<std::size_t N> struct Get
{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto operator()(const T& tuple) const 
    {
        return std::get<N>(tuple);
    }
};

Now you can write:
auto zipped = std::views::zip(x_values, y_values);

// Sort by first element (x_values)
std::ranges::sort(zipped, std::less{}, Get<0>{});

// Or ...sort by second element (y_values)
std::ranges::sort(zipped, std::less{}, Get<1>{});

// so on...

See a live demo

Thank you, it helps. Just to better understand pros and cons, taking into account introducing two new entities (struct template and functor template) what are the benefits against shorter solutions from Red.Wave and Jarod42 in the comments to original question? This is not "whose is better?" question, I just want to make sure that I am not missing some advantage of this solution against those for further occurrences.

@DamirTenishev The advantage of using functor are: (1) It can be specialized or partially specialized if needed (2) Follows a more traditional C++ design pattern therefore, may be more familiar to developers used to older C++ styles (3) works in older compilers (4)
Can be extended with additional member functions if needed. Cons are maybe: (1) More verbose, (2) Requires defining a new type. The choice between the both approaches, often comes down to coding style preferences, project conventions, and specific use cases.

@DamirTenishev  The lambda approach on the other hand: (1) Concise and readable
(2) Can be used inline without creating a named type (3)
Potentially more intuitive for developers familiar with modern C++ lambdas, Cons: (1) May be less flexible for complex scenarios (2) Cannot be specialized or partially specialized (3)
Might have limitations with older compilers... If you need detailed insights, maybe you can ask in codereview.stackexchange.com.

Yes, you just need to specify precisely which overload of std::get you want to use as the projection*.
In this case, you need the one taking a std::tuple<float&, float&> (since that's what elements of std::views::zip will give here). You can get the specific overload by casting to the appropriate function pointer:
std::ranges::sort(std::ranges::views::zip(x_values, y_values), std::less{}, 
        static_cast<float& (*)(std::tuple<float&, float&> const &)>(&std::get<0>));

demo
* Taking the address of functions in std is UB (unless they're designated as addressable functions, which isn't the case for get), but the general principle of specifying exact overloads to use as projections still applies.

It is bit uglier to do so, especially when you have some different non primitive types used in two containers that are zipping. Plus, more error prone, compared to the other solution.

And UB since C++20, as std::get is not an addressable function

@Jarod42 Indeed, edited to explain that.

Thank you, I noted that this not safe now. One related question here. If sort expects callable (like function pointer) as the third argument (projection), how &std::pair<int, int>::first has worked in ranges3 at all? I see that ranges3 used the same API for sorting, so how the field could have been used here? Or this is a topic for another question?

@DamirTenishev See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239287

Thank you so much. I put my clarifying question under the answer to that question. Curious to learn when this was introduced into the language.

std::get can be wrapped into lambda (and then used as functor) the following way:
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>

template <std::size_t I>
constexpr static inline auto tup_get
    = []<class Tup>(Tup&& tup) -> decltype(auto) {
          return std::get<I>(std::forward<Tup>(tup));
      };

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> x_values = { 3.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f };
    std::vector<float> y_values = { 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f };

    std::ranges::sort(std::views::zip(x_values, y_values), {}, tup_get<0>);
}

