# std::ranges::find_if - no type in std::common_reference

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'm using the SG14 [`flat_map`](https://github.com/WG21-SG14/SG14/blob/master/SG14/flat_map.h) as a container.

As per a standard map, it takes `Key` and `Value` template parameters.

Unlike a standard map, however, it doesn't store `std::pair<Key, Value>` in a binary search tree, but rather stores the keys and values in two separate containers (additional template arguments which default to `std::vector`)

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Mapped,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class KeyContainer = std::vector<Key>,
    class MappedContainer = std::vector<Mapped>
>
class flat_map
```

It then defines a number of types as follows:

```
using key_type = Key;
using mapped_type = Mapped;
using value_type = std::pair<const Key, Mapped>;
using key_compare = Compare;
using const_key_reference = typename KeyContainer::const_reference;
using mapped_reference = typename MappedContainer::reference;
using const_mapped_reference = typename MappedContainer::const_reference;
using reference = std::pair<const_key_reference, mapped_reference>;
using const_reference = std::pair<const_key_reference, const_mapped_reference>;
```

If I attempt to use `std::ranges::find_if` on the `flat_map`, I get an error:

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in 
    ‘struct std::common_reference<std::pair<const Key&, const Value&>&&, 
                                  std::pair<const Key, Value>&>’
  121 | auto it = std::ranges::find_if(map, [](auto& kv) { return kv.second.name == "foo"; });
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I use a non-range `find_if`, everything "just works"

```
auto it = std::find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), [](auto& kv) { return kv.second.name == "foo"; });
```

Why does the `std::ranges::find_if` not work?

Example on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/r93f7qozr

**Edit:**

@Brian provided an exemplar which successfully compiles - albeit with slight differences to mine - notably my map is `const`, and I take the lambda argument as a `const ref`...

This begs the questions:

- Why does the combination of `const` range and `const auto&` lambda argument fail to compile, while pasing a mutable range works and taking the lambda argument by value works?
- I believe it would be considered somewhat of an anti-pattern to take the non-range `std::find_if` algorithm's lambda arguments by value (`auto` as opposed to `const auto&`) as this will cause every element to be copied - and therefore using `const auto&` should be preferred... principle of least surprose means I assumed the same would be the case with `std::ranges` - is this not the case?

Comment: 1) Please provide a [mre] 2) [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/cY55annEe), `stdext::flat_map` seems to work fine with `std::ranges::find_if` on GCC and clang trunks.

Comment: You could also give a look at the possible implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/find). Maybe copy it over a new file so you can play around to see if the problem is that `flat_map` lacks something (alias member, member function such as `operator*`, and so on).

Comment: @Brian please find example here: https://godbolt.org/z/r93f7qozr (and I've updated the question to include the link)... notably the difference between mine and yours is that the map is const, and I take the lambda argument as const ref

Comment: @SteveLorimer Excellent, glad we narrowed that down! It may be worth noting that you get the same error with [non-const references and a mutable map](https://godbolt.org/z/T9j8rxqe5) but _not_ with [const references and a mutable map](https://godbolt.org/z/3fvWj7fa1)

Comment: Note, I would write it like `auto it1 = std::ranges::find(map, 0, &decltype(map)::value_type::second);` but anyhow, that doesn't work either. You get a lot of requirements not met, like _"no type named 'type' in 'struct std::common_reference<std::pair<const int&, const int&>&&, std::pair<const int, int>&>'"_

Comment: @JHBonarius +1 for the projection!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does the combination of `const` range and `const auto&` lambda
> argument fail to compile, while pasing a mutable range works and
> taking the lambda argument by value works?

First, the `operator*()` of the iterator of `flat_map` is defined as follows:

```
reference operator*() const {
  return reference{*kit_, *vit_};
}
```

And the type of `reference` is `pair`, this means that `operator*()` will return a *prvalue* of `pair`, so the parameter type of the lambda cannot be `auto&`, that is, an lvalue reference, because it cannot bind rvalue.

Second, `const flat_map` does not model the [`input_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/input_range) concept, that is, its iterator does not model `input_iterator` which requires [`indirectly_readable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_readable) which requires `common_reference_with<iter_reference_t<In>&&, iter_value_t<In>&>`, the former is `pair<const int&, const int&>&&`, and the latter is `pair<const int, int>&`, there is no `common_reference` for the two.

The workaround is to just define `common_reference` for them, just like [P2321](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2321r2.html#pair) does (which also means that your code is well-formed in C++23):

```
template<class T1, class T2, class U1, class U2,
         template<class> class TQual, template<class> class UQual>
  requires requires { typename pair<common_reference_t<TQual<T1>, UQual<U1>>,
                                    common_reference_t<TQual<T2>, UQual<U2>>>; }
struct basic_common_reference<pair<T1, T2>, pair<U1, U2>, TQual, UQual> {
  using type = pair<common_reference_t<TQual<T1>, UQual<U1>>,
                    common_reference_t<TQual<T2>, UQual<U2>>>;
};
```

For details on `common_reference`, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011331/what-is-the-purpose-of-c20-stdcommon-reference).