# Is it still impossible to sort a range with proxy iterators whose value_type/reference is pair in C++23?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

Although [P2321 `zip`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2321r2.html#pair) provides the [`common_reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011331/what-is-the-purpose-of-c20-stdcommon-reference) specialization for `pair`, and [P2165 Compatibility between `tuple`, `pair` and `tuple`-like objects](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf) makes `tuple` and `pair` interconvertible, the comparison function of `pair` only has the following candidates in [[pairs.spec]](https://eel.is/c++draft/pairs.spec):

```
template<class T1, class T2>
  constexpr common_comparison_category_t<...>
    operator<=>(const pair<T1, T2>& x, const pair<T1, T2>& y);
```

Noted that there are *only* two template parameters here, so we still cannot compare two different `pair`s, [for example](https://godbolt.org/z/T6ov9K5K4):

```
using value_type = pair<int , string >;
using reference  = pair<int&, string&>;

value_type val = {1, "a"};
reference  ref = val;
val < ref; // no match for 'operator<'
```

This means that a proxy iterator using a `pair` as `value_type`/`reference` always failed to satisfy the [`sortable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sortable) concept, that is, `iter_value_t<I>` must be comparable with `iter_reference_t<I>`, which indicates that `ranges::sort` won't work for such a class of iterators (such as `zip_view::iterator` before [P2165](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf)) unless manually pass in a custom comparator:

```
std::vector<int> x, y;
ranges::sort(std::views::zip(x, y)); // This won't work before P2165 
 // because the reference type of zip_view is pair<int&, int&>,
 // which cannot be compared with its value type pair<int, int>.

 // After P2165 its reference type was changed to tuple<int&, int&>, 
 // which works because it can be compared with its value type tuple<int, int>.
```

Why *doesn't* the standard introduce heterogeneous `pair` comparisons to support sorting a range with such kinds of iterators even in C++23? Is this intentional? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This sounds like a defect. You may want to [report it as such](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-issue), since C++23 isn't finished yet.

Comment: you mean without custom comparator right?. actually I don't think this really relate to range.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the standard introduce heterogeneous `pair` comparisons to support sorting a range with such kinds of iterators even in C++23?

[LWG-3865 "Sorting a range of `pair`s"](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3865) does exactly that. It was recently merged into the C++23 Working Draft at the 2023-02 WG21 meeting. ("Recently" as in "the updated working draft hasn't been completed as of this writing", so don't be surprised if you can't find it in the most recent draft.)