# Why doesn't this code using std::ranges::find on an std::views::zip compile?

Tags: c++, std, std-ranges, c++23

The following C++23 code does not compile with gcc:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> v2{2,4,6,8};
    auto z = std::views::zip(v1, v2);

    if(std::ranges::find(z, {2, 4}) != z.end()) {
        std::cout << "(2,4) in zip\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
zip.cpp:11:25: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::ranges::__find_fn) (std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >&, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

If I change the code as follows:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> v2{2,4,6,8};
    auto z = std::views::zip(v1, v2);

    if(std::ranges::find_if(z, [](auto p){return p == std::make_pair(2, 4);}) != z.end()) {
        std::cout << "(2,4) in zip\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error is more comprehensible:

```
zip.cpp:10:52: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::pair<int&, int&>’ and ‘std::pair<int, int>’)
```

Is there a way to make similar code compile?
To be clear, what I want to achieve is to verify if a pair of elements is in a zip view. I.e., if the first element is in the first vector, the second element is in the second vector, and their indices are equal.

Comment: [P2165](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf) makes the value type of `zip_view` always be `tuple`, and adds comparison functions with `tuple`-like objects for `tuple`, so `ranges::find(z, pair-or-tuple-or-array{2, 4})` in C++23 is well-formed (since `tuple` can be compared with `pair` or `tuple`). The reason why your code will fail is because the proposal has not been fully implemented by various compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code tries to compare a `pair<int,int>` with a `pair<int&,int&>`. It should be OK, however it seems that none of the mainstream compilers have conforming implementations of `operator==` for pairs yet.

Published standards used to specify

```
template<class T1, class T2>
constexpr bool operator==(const pair<T1,T2>&, const pair<T1,T2>&);
```

which is what all current implementations do. However a relatively new [defect report](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3865) changes this to

```
template<class T1, class T2, class U1, class U2>
constexpr bool operator==(const pair<T1,T2>&, const pair<U1,U2>&);
```

which fixes the problem. It has not made its way into the compilers yet.

You will have to provide your own custom comparator until the implementations catch up with the DR.

Comment: "*however it seems that none of the mainstream compilers have conforming implementations of operator== for pairs.*" See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75268007/is-it-still-impossible-to-sort-a-range-with-proxy-iterators-whose-value-type-ref

Comment: @康桓瑋 ah so cppreference is wrong, it says the heterogeneous comparison was there from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, defining `bool operator==(const std::pair<int&, int&>& p1, const std::pair<int, int>& p2)` fixes the second example. However, it still does not fix the first one. What operator should I define, if any, to make the first (more concise) code sample work?

Comment: @AlbertoSantini I don't think you can do anything there except provide `std::pair<int&, int&>` as an argument.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit It is not really wrong, it's just the way that cppreference handles DR is confusing. If a DR has been retroactively applied to previous standards, it will be shown as being applicable to previous standards in cppreference and then the original DR report is added to the "Defect reports" section of the page.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Thanks, I didn't realise it was retroactively applied.