# Inconsistent behavior of std::common_reference_with on tuples. Which is correct?

Tags: c++, tuples, language-lawyer, c++-concepts, std

### Background:

I'm trying to port a library to compile on MSVC.
That library stores data in a tuple of vectors (`std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>`), and uses a custom iterator to iterate over all vectors simultaneously (similar to what a zip_iterator does).

The iterator defines types that look like this (assuming `Ts...` -> `<int, int>`) :

```
`value_type` is `std::tuple<int, int>`  
`reference`  is `std::tuple<int&, int&>`
```

The problem is that on latest MSVC (v. 19.35), this iterator does not satisfy the concept of [`std::input_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator), while it does satisfy it on gcc/clang.

On further investigation, i found the failure to be due to inconsistent behaviour of the [`std::common_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference) concept on tuples.

### Issue:

The following `static_assert` fails on MSVC, while it doesn't fail on gcc/clang

```
using T = std::tuple<int, int>&;
using U = std::tuple<int&, int&>;
static_assert(std::common_reference_with<T, U>, "failed common_reference_with");
```

Here it is on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ns3cqzW6G) (with an iterator example as well)

### Question:

Is a type like `std::tuple<int, int>&` supposed to have a "`common_reference_with`" `std::tuple<int&, int&>` ? MSVC says no, gcc says yes.
Which of the two behaviours should be expected according to the standard in C++20 and forward?

Is there any easy way to make this iterator succeed the iterator concept checks on MSVC (ie, force the two types to have a common reference)?

I also found some great answers by Eric Niebler, on [std::common_reference (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59024241/22400021) and on [proxy iterators (on his blog)](https://ericniebler.com/2015/01/28/to-be-or-not-to-be-an-iterator/).

However, it's not clear to me what is supposed to happen in C++20 and later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is a type like `std::tuple<int, int>&` supposed to have a
> "common_reference_with" `std::tuple<int&, int&>` ?

Yes, [P2321](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2321r2.html) guarantees that they have common reference type `tuple<int&, int&>` and model `common_reference_with`.

Since such enhancement of `common_reference` for `tuple` is a C++23 feature, you need to change the MSVC compiler option to `/std:c++latest` to [make it work](https://godbolt.org/z/a1c74ox7q).

It is worth noting that [P2165](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf) makes `tuple` compatible with other `tuple`-like objects such as `array`, `pair` and `ranges::subrange`, so it also has a valid `common_reference` type with the other three.