# How to write a C++23 constant_range factory a la iota, with by-value dereference operator

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std-ranges, c++23

I have written a range factory very similar to iota, but generating instances of a user-defined type. The synopsis looks something like this:

```cpp
struct MyType;

struct MyIterator {
    using value_type = MyType;
    using iterator_concept  = std::input_iterator_tag;
    // ...
    auto operator*() const -> MyType;
};

struct MyView : public std::ranges::view_interface<MyView> {
    auto begin() const -> MyIterator;
    auto end() const -> MyIterator;
};
```

I've done my best to make this follow iota_view's design. However, I find that `MyView` is not a constant range:

```cpp
static_assert( std::ranges::constant_range<std::ranges::iota_view<int>>);
static_assert(!std::ranges::constant_range<MyView>); // Not a constant_range!
```

After looking at [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/constant_range), I traced this back to `MyIterator` not being a `constant-iterator` because:

- `std::same_as<std::iter_const_reference_t<MyIterator>, std::iter_reference_t<MyIterator>>` doesn't hold because
- `std::iter_reference_t<MyIterator>` is `MyType` but `std::iter_const_reference_t<MyIterator>` is `const MyType`.

If I replace `MyType` with `int`, just like `iota_view`, then both are non-const.

So I went to figure out where the difference comes from, and it turns out that `std::iter_const_reference_t` is defined in terms of `std::common_reference_t`, which has been extensively covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011331/what-is-the-purpose-of-c20-stdcommon-reference). And it, in turn, has this complicated strategy to figure out the resulting type, but actually both `int` and `MyType` fall into the same branch, which is (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference)):

```cpp
template<class T> T val();
decltype(false? val<const T&&>() : val<T>())
```

And it turns out that this is `int` if `T` is `int`, and `const MyType` if `T` is `MyType`.

I don't know why the conditional operator resolves types like that, but anyway I cannot change it; but fortunately the standard allows me to inject my own behavior by specializing `std::basic_common_reference`, which I can do for example like this:

```cpp
template<template<class> class TQual, template<class> class UQual>
struct std::basic_common_reference<MyType, MyType, TQual, UQual>
{
    using type = std::common_type_t<TQual<MyType>, UQual<MyType>>;
};
```

And, indeed, this fixes the issue. But I have no idea whether this is correct or even intended to be used like that. In general, it doesn't seem very practical since there is nothing range-specific about `MyType` - it just happens to be the type I'm generating, and in my real use case it's a template parameter of the view. Which means that whether the view conforms to constant_view entirely depends on whether the type it's templated on has this basic_common_reference specialization... which seems odd.

For your reference, here is a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hbhsav9To) link.

So here, finally, is the question: What is the correct way to implement a constant_view with an lvalue reference type? Appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to return a const `MyType` object:

```
struct MyIterator {
    // ...
    auto operator*() const -> const MyType;
};

static_assert(std::ranges::constant_range<MyView>);
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I was trying to get rid of the const qualification, but this is simply embracing it. Are there any downsides to this? It used to be discouraged to return by const value.

Comment: I see no obvious downsides. However, I am more curious about why the original design of `constant-iterator` excluded the iterator that returns prvalue objects even though it does not modify the elements of the original range. Maybe it takes into account the iterator that returns the proxy reference? It's difficult to fully understand the rationale behind the formula of `common_reference` (`iter_const_reference_t`) design without asking the original author.